# What could 'Roaming not allowed by server' of ssh client mean?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm failing to connect to an SSH server instance and the verbose output contains `debug1: Roaming not allowed by server`. The following predictable and there avoidable problems arise:

- Roaming means to access services from different types of networks. I can't figure out what it could mean in the context of the verbose output of a `ssh` 6.6.1 client running on Ubuntu 14.04.
- It is not clear whether this is an error or not and if it is whether it is causing the failure of the login or not (I don't want to dive into the connection failure here, though; none of the output message of `ssh` does BTW -> more problems and time waisting - you have been warned!)
- I queried `site:www.openssh.org roaming` in google with empty result and manpages don't contain the term. It is nonsense to use it even if it was documented because of its ambiguity!

What could the message mean? How could I use it to debug the large set of other highly ambiguous, unintuitive and unhelpful error and other messages of SSH?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not really an error message. It's just a debug message telling you that the server doesn't accept roaming connections.

Roaming is apparently an experimental feature added to OpenSSH back in 2009 or so. The purpose of the feature is to let an ssh client disconnect from a server session and then resume the session from another location. See [here](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-April/028589.html) ([Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141011021516/http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-April/028589.html)) for some discussion about it. Googling ssh, roaming, and "Martin Forssén" will turn up other pages. It doesn't look like it's being actively developed. I suspect the SSH developers never documented it because it's experimental and perhaps not finished.

From inspecting the OpenSSH source code, there's an undocumented client-side option `UseRoaming` which can be set to yes or no. Adding the line "UseRoaming no" to your client configuration (normally your `.ssh/config` file) ought to suppress the debug message.

It wasn't obvious to me why the server-side `HostbasedAuthentication` setting would control whether the server accepts roaming connections or not.

Update: The client roaming support is apparently the subject of a computer vulnerability exposure report, [CVE-2016-0777](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2016-0777). OpenSSH versions 5.4 through 7.1p1 are vulnerable. Users should upgrade to OpenSSH 7.1p2 or later. Users who cannot upgrade should disable roaming in the client by adding "UseRoaming no" to their ssh client configuration. See the following:

- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-0777
- https://www.qualys.com/2016/01/14/cve-2016-0777-cve-2016-0778/openssh-cve-2016-0777-cve-2016-0778.txt
- http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20160114142733
- https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/openssh-client-bug-cve-2016-0777.54736/

Comment: Well, it is now recommended to set it to no. http://www.mail-archive.com/misc@openbsd.org/msg144351.html

Comment: @nikeee: ...and that's a cautionary story for not shipping "harmless" non-working stubs. (Note that you need to set it to `no` in *client* settings, not on the server)

Comment: @Piskvor but there's a quite a few devops / webops books that propagate doing that.. could they be all wrong? Oh.

Comment: best explanation about this config on the net.

Answer (score 4):

The changelog from openssh 5.3 on CentOS6 has a note:

```
2009/06/27
     Add client option UseRoaming. It doesn't do anything yet but will
     control whether the client tries to use roaming if enabled on the
     server. From Martin Forssen.
```

Answer (score 3):

@ILMostro_7 chmod 600 authorized_keys worked fine for me.

For the benefit of anyone else who arrives here by googling "Roaming not allowed by server", and is using a Linux (Ubuntu) client, you might fix *that* warning and *then* see:-

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key
```

The cure for that is given at https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/

```
    # start the ssh-agent in the background
    $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    # Agent pid 59566 (displays process id)
    $ ssh-add
    # Enter passphrase for /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa: [tippy tap]
    # Identity added: /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

'#' = comment. you = your-username. [tippy tap] = humo[u]r? = press the Enter key.

I hope that helps somebody as much as this Q&A already helped me.

Answer (score 2):

This error message can show up when `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` doesn't have  `HostbasedAuthentication` set to `yes` on the server.

I have no idea why.

Another issue may be:

> Check the permissions on the $USER/.ssh directory which should be owned by the user and be chmod 700. The authorized_keys file should also be chmod 700 and owned by the user

Comment: 700? Why would you need `execute` bit on keyfile?

Comment: Where's the quote from? Please add a reference.

Comment: ILMostro_7 isn't not on the file, it's on the directory, and for the user to be able to create files in the directory, the execute flag must be set

Comment: @IceyEC The answer suggests 700 for *authorized_keys*.

Comment: Should be `chmod 400`. No idea why I'd ever want *that* file to be executable; and write access is also not desirable 99.999% of the time. `sshd` checks that the user's `.ssh` folder has no access for group and other, and likewise for `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Therefore, the perms in the answer might work, but they're unnecessarily wide.

Comment: @mdrozdziel you're right, I was responding to the first half before reading the rest of the recommendation!